# How to separate execution and compilation from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am currently developing a Rust application for Windows from Linux. I'm looking to containerize this application. I would like to write a Dockerfile that does the following:

- **Build image**: From `archlinux:multilib-devel` do updates, install `rust`, install `mingw-64` and install target `i686-pc-windows-gnu`
- **Execution**: From a volume mounted on the host at `$PWD` and pointing to `/build` on the container, compile the Rust project (and make sure it's mirrored on the host).

Here's my current Dockerfile :

```
FROM archlinux:multilib-devel

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm && \
    pacman -S --needed --noconfirm rustup mingw-w64

RUN rustup default stable && \
    rustup target install i686-pc-windows-gnu

WORKDIR /app

VOLUME /build

CMD ["cd build && cargo build --target i686-pc-windows-gnu && cargo build --release --target i686-pc-windows-gnu"]
```

Here's my command to build the image : `docker build -t 'wrapper' .`

Here is my command to run the container : `docker run -v ${PWD}:/build wrapper`

I get the following error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "cd build && cargo build --target i686-pc-windows-gnu && cargo build --release --target i686-pc-windows-gnu": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Here's how my project is organized:

```bash
❯ tree
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    ├── api.rs
    ├── client.rs
    ├── main.rs
    ├── service.rs
    └── system.rs

2 directories, 9 files
```

How do I fix my Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just got the wrong syntax for your [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#cmd) the arguments are supposed to be different strings: `["cd", "build", …]` etc, I'm not sure multiple commands are supported with `&&` like you did you probably just want to use multiple [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run) statements instead.

Comment: @cafce25 No, I can't use multiple `RUN` instructions because they are executed both during image construction and at runtime. `CMD []` is only used during execution.

Comment: then you'll have to see if separating the separate arguments works: `["cd", "build", "&&", …]`, though the `"cd", "build"` part most definitely can be replaced by a `WORKDIR` directive. If that doesn't work you'll have to add a script that does all of your commands and call that as a single command.

Comment: I don't think `&&` in particular will work: that's a shell-specific construct. So you will need to either have a shell script as suggested by @cafce25 or call the shell explicitly: `[ "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd build && cargo build ..." ]`

Comment: Drop the JSON array syntax on the CMD if you want to run shell commands there (including `cd` and `&&`). Just `CMD cd build && cargo build --target i686-pc-windows-gnu && cargo build --release --target i686-pc-windows-gnu`